# ElasticSearch cluster on docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and docker. Recently I ran my single node elasticsearch cluster by using 
`docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0` command.
Once by mistake I forgot to mention environment variable **"discovery.type=single-node"** due to which elastic search failed to start.
I want to understand why it won't start up without it.

Also I know we can start the elasticsearch cluster using docker compose. But I wanted to run above mentioned command one by one instead of using docker compose so that node is added to cluster one by one for experimenting purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have detailed info about why you need to specify `discovery.type=single-node`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html

Long story short, as you are not connecting to a cluster, you need to specify such setting to be able to run elasticsearch.

About docker-compose vs standalone docker runs, it's rather the same. Just bear in mind that you **can't** use the same command, you need to properly pass settings to connect to your cluster's master. Have a read at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html#targetText=discovery.type,forms%20a%20single%2Dnode%20cluster.